# Why does javascript:alert("foo" & "bar"); display zero?

Tags: javascript

I really think the title explains it thoroughly enough.  I stumbled upon this oddity when I used an ampersand instead of a plus sign in some string manipulation code.  Found it interesting.  Could somebody explain this for me?

Comment: Wow, nice job on the double-quotes, StackOverflow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because all bitwise operators**<sup>1</sup>**, including the bitwise and (`&`), work with 32-bit integers.

This operator will convert the two operands to signed 32-bit integers using the abstract `ToInt32` operation **<sup>2</sup>**, and if the value is not a number, the result of this conversion is `0`.

At the end your expression becomes evaluated as:

```
0 & 0; // 0
```

References:

1. *Binary Bitwise Operators* [ECMA-262, 3rd. Ed.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) Section 11.10
2. `ToInt32`, [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), Section 9.5

Comment: While I think @Tor tipped me off the quickest, I'll +1 you because you provided reference and and final expression.

Comment: Extraneous `&` on the final expression there.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript, like many languages, has a bit operator &
This compares the bits at similar positions and returns a 1-bit in those positions where they both have a 1-bit and a 0-bit in those positions where either one has a 0-bit.

And the important thing why it returns 0 is not because no bits match, but because it doesn't support strings. :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting theory, but `"foo" & "foo"` returns 0 as well.

Comment: @Breton Actually I believe he is correct.  You could use any strings and the result would be the same.  Bitwise operators are for numeric values, not strings.  Please revert your vote.  Thanks, @Tor!

Comment: He edited his answer, and for some reason it doesn't mark it as edited. Oh well. Reverted.

Comment: Yeah I edited it... there's probably by design a short gap where edits aren't picked up. :)

Comment: Ooops, can't revert my vote unless the post has been edited. A bug in stack overflow?! never!

Answer (score 1):

**&** is the bitwise AND operator (as opposed to **&&**, which is the logical AND operator). A bitwise & makes no sense on strings, so I suppose JavaScript just takes the easy way out and returns 0.

There could be a more technical explanation, but basically you gave a nonsensical instruction and got back a nonsensical result. It would have been nicer to get an error, but JavaScript is just not that kind of language!

Comment: +1 on the Lack of error message.  Should have been a syntax error, at least!

Answer (score 0):

that's a bitwise & which is casting its arguments to be numbers. when you cast an arbitrary string to a number, and that string doesn't contain numerical text, then the result is NaN.

the result of NaN & NaN is 0 for some reason.

try "2" & "3"